A model for illfounded set theory
As title states, I'm interested in figuring out how to construct a model of $\mathsf{ZFC} + \neg\mathsf{Reg}$, preferably off any regular model $\langle M, \in_M \rangle$ of $\mathsf{ZFC}$ without any forcing shenanigans involved.
As I'm still working on the problem and don't want to spoil myself the fun, I want to clarify that I am not looking for an actual solution/model construction here, but rather to just know whether the following (suspiciously simple) idea actually works in any way:
Take some model $\langle M, \in_M \rangle$ of $\mathsf{ZFC}$. As $\langle M, \in_M\rangle \models \exists x \ \nexists y \ y \in x$, there must be some (unique) $\emptyset_M \in M$ such that $(m, \emptyset_M) \mathop{\notin} \in_M$ for all $m \in M$. Let us now do the following:
(1) Remove the ordered pair $(\emptyset_M, \{\emptyset\}_M)$ from $\in_M$.
(2) Add the new ordered pair $(\emptyset_M, \emptyset_M)$ to $\in_M$. Call the resulting relation $\in'_M$.
After having done so, $\{\emptyset\}_M$ should now be playing the role (internally) of the empty set in the model $\langle M, \in'_M\rangle$, whilst $\emptyset_M$ now plays the role of a solely selfcontaining set, in explicit contradiction with $\mathsf{Reg}$.
What is wrong with/doesn't work about this idea?
Many thanks in advance to any and all responses.

Nothing is wrong with it. It works! (Though you should be careful to verify in detail that you haven't broken any axioms other than the one you wanted to break.)
The following is not a proof that your idea does work, nor any kind of worked-out proof, but rather some context on your idea and related constructions... nonetheless I'll put it in a "spoiler" box per your request.

This is a special case of a Rieger-Bernays permutation model, where we take $F$ to be any permutation of $M$ and let $x\in 'y$ if and only if $x\in F(y).$ One can show $(M,\in')\models \sf ZFC-Reg$ whenever $(M,\in)\models \sf ZFC,$ and different choices of $F$ can yield all sorts of violations of regularity; your choice is the same as letting $F$ be the permutation swapping $\emptyset$ and $\{\emptyset\}.$ You can see a brief treatment in Kunen's Set Theory (2013), section II.9. One can also just build other types of regularity-violation "by hand", similarly to how you did, though the permutation approach is  more systematic. As another ad hoc approach, it is perhaps somewhat easier to first construct a model of set theory with atoms, and then we can wire up the atoms to violate regularity however we like, then identify some sets to restore extensionality.


Thanks for the quick and detailed response! :)
